# How to set VCL custom style "Light" on owner drawn TColorButton?

Tags: windows, delphi, button, vcl, vcl-styles

I am modifying my windows desktop VCL project (windows) style to custom style "Light".

I am having trouble to modify an owner drawn TColorButton Delphi component (
http://delphi.about.com/od/vclwriteenhance/l/aa061104a.htm ) to "Light" custom style.

When I set my project style to custom style "Light", TColorButton acts like a normal TButton (colour can't be modify) with Light style. I understood after gone through other questions on this site that, I should unset style elements client (i.e **StyleElemets.seClient := false**) to change back ground colour. But, it resets the style of delphi component TColorButton to standard windows style.

Could you please suggest me, how to overcome above issue ?

VCL Light custom style has a different back ground colour when mouse over/onclick event on the button. Is it possible to get hex value of colour?

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: It appears this `TColorButton` was designed for Delphi 7, long before styles were introduced. The whole component will have to be modified to take this into consideration.

Comment: As an alternative, you can take advantage of the styles - modify the style to color the buttons the way you want. Because that old Windows 95 style button is an eye sore anyway.